# How to avoid exception on Logger.Write() when configuration has been removed?

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

If the user removes the logging configuration from App.Config, an ActivationException is raised when `Logger.Write("test")` is called.

What is the best way to test for this *without* raising an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, I don't think there is a foolproof way to determine if an exception will be raised.  I'm not sure about the specific details of your application but one  approach would be to attempt to log a message at application startup.  E.g. "Application Starting."  If it succeeds, great.  If it throws an exception then catch the exception and configure Enterprise Library using the [fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_logging) with a default configuration.  Then you can log a message indicating the application startup logging failure.

After application startup Enterprise Library should most probably be properly configured and subsequent Logger.Write's should succeed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there are a few ways to deal with this issue, but if you want to make sure not to raise an exception because the logging configuration has been removed, I'd use the "ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration" from the System.Configuration namespace to examine the file at runtime to check if the sections and data is there that I was expecting.

Comment: +1 because this will work, but I was looking for something simpler.  I think the point of the enterprise library is that I don't have to write code to read config files.  I'm probably being overly idealistic...

Comment: @Greg: It should be able to detect a missing configuration but I think it's still possible to throw an exception if the section is there but the user has misconfigured (perhaps by accident) the file. E.g. invalid type.